# Karma ng test does not show build errors in console

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma with Jasmine to execute tests in my Angular 7 project. However I'm running into a very irritating scenario, where if there are any errors in the `.spec.ts` (or `.ts`) files, running `ng test` does not show these errors in the console.

For instance, if I have a duplicate import in a file:

```
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent { ... }
```

the normal `ng serve` reports this as an error. However, running `ng test` does not always do this, it just fails to run the tests, opening chrome with a blank page, saying `'Waiting for localhost...'`, and eventually just fails:

```
> ng test
10 % building modules 3 / 3 modules 0 active30 08 2019 11: 28: 31.213: WARN[karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
30 08 2019 11: 28: 31.296: INFO[karma - server]: Karma v4.2.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
30 08 2019 11: 28: 31.297: INFO[launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
10 % building modules 4 / 5 modules 1 active ...b\projects\myProject\src\styles.scss30 08 2019 11: 28: 31.720: INFO[launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
30 08 2019 11: 29: 31.722: WARN[launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
30 08 2019 11: 29: 31.994: INFO[launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again(1 / 2).
30 08 2019 11: 30: 31.996: WARN[launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
30 08 2019 11: 30: 32.277: INFO[launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again(2 / 2).
30 08 2019 11: 31: 32.279: WARN[launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
30 08 2019 11: 31: 32.530: ERROR[launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times(timeout).Giving up.
```

This makes it very difficult to figure out why Karma doesnt launch the tests, and just opens a blank window, with the cryptic message `Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.`

I have tried setting the log level from [the config file documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/configuration-file.html), but it doesn't even seem to get to this point where it loads karma, because the actual build fails before that (I think).

How can I get the build to report these errors in the `spec.ts` files?

---

**Edit**

Running the command with `--watch=false` reports the compilation errors. Similarly, if you make a change in a spec file, causing the rebuild to trigger (if you have `--watch=true`), the compilation error is also printed in the console through the cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the ideal solution, but this works from the original question:

> Running the command with `--watch=false` reports the compilation errors. Similarly, if you make a change in a spec file, causing the rebuild to trigger (if you have `--watch=true`), the compilation error is also printed in the console through the cli.